# "Invalid Argument: dirname" in Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-elcapitan, bin, dirname

I noticed the issue when I first went to run

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

in macOS terminal (10.11.2) but this was returned

```
bash: /usr/bin/defaults: Invalid argument
```

I'm not sure what is going on with defaults, but I also have a similar issue with brew:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/dirname: Invalid argument
```

I clearly broke something, but not sure how I did it or when it happened. This is causing all sorts of issues. Any thoughts on fixing it?

Comment: more suited for apple.stackexchange.com or superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled El Capitan from the recovery partition (restart holding command-R), and it solved the issue. My guess is that the xcode command tools were to blame.